# Change Frame Location in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to iterate through an array of urls to set as locations for a frame.  So far what I have is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDCqz/):

```
var l = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
         '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
         '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'];

$(document).ready(function () { // Wait until body is ready to be manipulated
    l.forEach(function (query) { // iterate through l
        $('#g').on('load', function () { // Wait until #g is loaded
            $('#g').attr('location', 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + query); // goto Bing search
        });
    });
});
```

When I go to run it, though, nothing happens in the Result pane.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zDCqz/3/

It's work with iframe and src attr.

Comment: if one answer suits you, would you mind tag one as the final solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $ifr = $('#g');
    function load() {
        if (l.length) {
            $ifr.one('load', load);
            $ifr[0].src = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + l.shift();
        }
    }
    load();
});
```

I think you should change `src` attribute of the iframe, not `location`.

Comment: you mean on('load'), not one, right? ;)
by the way, I've never managed to get the load event of the iframe. does it really work?

Comment: No, I meant `one`, because we only want the event handler to be executed once per url change.

Comment: Well, I couldn't ever get it to work in Fiddle, but after some tweaking, I got your version to work!  http://pastebin.com/4QHX9YgR

Comment: @KevinOrr & dfsq :  I was surprised because it worked for frame! you both are using it for iframes where the main problem lied in <frame> itself! http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2a1quIzox1r6zm3i.png

Answer (score 1):

You have frame with id- frame. change Id to something else. Did you mean iframe? Use contentWindow instead of window. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDCqz/6/)

```
$('#myframe')[0].contentWindow.location = 
                       'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + query;
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer, but the implementation doesn't wait for each page to load, it *does* iterate through all of them, but so quickly that they don't have a chance to load.  But thanks for teaching me about `contentWindow`!

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to use an iframe for this (or an [Object-Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp))

How about this?

```
$(function(){
  var l = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
  '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
  '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'],
  idx = 0;


(function(){
    if(idx < l.length){
        $('#frame').attr("src",'http://www.bing.com/search?q='+l[idx]) ;
        idx++;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee,5000);
    }    

}())

})
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is `arguments.callee`?.  Also are you using `#frame` for `#g`?  If so, **I** should probably change my original code, as `#frame` makes more sense.

Comment: Alright, this works.  The only unfortunate thing is that it invariably waits 5 seconds, which could be way too long or way too short.